# saving emails downloaded from an IMAP server using libcurl and C++ to a file

Tags: c++, imap, libcurl

I am able to fetch emails from an IMAP server but I am unable to save them to a file on my computer for later processing. Is there a way to do this in C++ using libcurl?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* Set username and password */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "username");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "password");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX/;UID=1");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    /* Perform the fetch */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* Always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  return (int)res;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to write what the actual problem is. What do you mean by "I am unable to save them to a file"? What happens? What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing a data transfer with:

```
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

But you are not doing anything with that data. You must set a callback function that will be called whenever `curl_easy_perform(curl)` returns `CURLE_OK`.

Here is what [libcurl tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html) says:

> Let's assume for a while that you want to receive data as the URL identifies a remote resource you want to get here. Since you write a sort of application that needs this transfer, I assume that you would like to get the data passed to you directly instead of simply getting it passed to stdout. So, you write your own function that matches this prototype:
>
> ```
> size_t write_data(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp);
> ```
>
> You tell libcurl to pass all data to this function by issuing a function similar to this:
>
> ```
> curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
> ```